# vacation care for indoor plants

Tags: indoors, watering, herbs

I recently bought self-watering pots.

Currently, I am using it for Rosemary. But, is it even a good idea to use self-watering pots for indoor herbs?

Which plants or herbs are good for self-watering pots?

Also, herbs tend to affect most when I am away for 1 or 2 weeks. How, can I not kill them if not using self-watering pots.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how exactly your pots work.

Some self-watering pots make the soil always wet, which won’t work for some herbs (like onion). Check your plant water requirements.

Rosemary is a drought-resistant plant and it doesn’t need much water. If rosemary is happy and your other herbs are similar (oregano, thyme) it will definitely work.

Another ways to help plants survive for two weeks are putting the pots into a big bowl of water (works only for plants who don’t mind living in the swamp), or simply watering them very well and putting to a humid shadowed place without wind.

If you have just a few plants, it is a good idea to bring them to your office/friend for someone to water.